# Do minor improvement actions have any meaning in the family version of Agricola?

Tags: agricola

Using the Agricola family ruleset, when a card specifically refers to "minor improvements" (for example "After family growth, play a minor improvement"), do I  ignore it or interpret it as "play a Major improvement"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [rules](http://www.zmangames.com/boardgames/files/agricola/Agricola_Rules.pdf) are pretty clear, the Minor Improvement cards are not used, so you ignore it.

> **Agricola as a Family Game (for 1-5 people from 10 years)**
>
> In the simplified version of Agricola, the Occupation and **Minor Improvement cards are not used** - players do not have a hand of cards.
>
> The first game board is turned face down, showing the "Agricola Family Game" side, and in a 3-5 player game only the "Family Game" Action cards are used.
>
> The Major or Minor Improvement action is restricted to Major Improvements.
>
> Otherwise, the rules are the same as for the full game.

Comment: I didn't think the rules were clear on this point though.  A line could have been added to the rules to deal specifically with that card.